# Boot to SATA drive in other computer?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I have a MacBook Pro that does not seem to be booting. If I were to take the hard drive and put it in another computer an select that in the BIOS, would it boot (if the hardware between the two computers are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will boot in another Mac.

Comment: Great that it can boot in a mac, but will it boot in a Dell?

Comment: No, it will not boot in a Dell.